# Is the use of "||" in a substring search prohibited?

Tags: perl

I have a little Perl script which includes a substring search as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "this && is || a test if && ||";

my $nb_if = findSymbols($line, "if ");
my $nb_and = findSymbols($line, "&&");
my $nb_or = findSymbols($line, "||");

print "\nThe result for this func is $nb_if=if , $nb_and=and, $nb_or=or\n";

sub findSymbols {
    my $n = () = ($_[0] =~ m/$_[1]/g);
    return $n;
}
```

It should return:

`The result for this func is 1=if , 2=and, 2=or`

but, instead it returns:

`The result for this func is 1=if , 2=and, 30=or`

I don't understand what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is the alternation operator in the regular expression used by `m//`. You need to escape each `|` with a backslash to match literal `|`s.

```
my $nb_or = findSymbols($line, "\\|\\|");  # or '\|\|`
```

(but using `quotemeta` as [suggested by @toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69540830/1126841) is a much better idea, as it frees your caller from having to worry about details that should be part of the abstraction provided by `findSymbols`.)

Answer (score 4):

Use [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) to escape the special meaning of the regular expression containing `||` (and any other characters which you pass to the function):

```
sub findSymbols {
    my $pat = quotemeta $_[1];
    my $n = () = ($_[0] =~ m/$pat/g);
    return $n;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The pipe character (`|`) has a special meaning in regular expressions. It means "or" (matching either the thing on its left or the thing on its right). So having a regex that consists of just two pipes is interpreted as meaning "match an empty string or an empty string or an empty string" - and that matches everywhere in your string (30 times!)

So you need to stop the pipe being interpreted as a special character and let it just represent an actual pipe character. Here are three ways to do that:

1. Escape the pipes with backslashes when you're creating the string that you pass to `findSymbols()`.

   ```
   # Note: I've also changed "..." to '...'
   # to avoid having to double-escape
   my $nb_or = findSymbols($line, '\|\|');
   ```
2. Use [`quotemeta()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) to automatically escape problematic characters in any string passed to `findSymbols()`.

   ```
   my $escaped_regex = quotemeta($_[0]);
   my $n = () = ($_[0] =~ m/$escaped_regex/g);
   ```
3. Use `\Q...\E` to automatically escape any problematic characters used in your regex.

   ```
   # Note: In this case, the \E isn't actually needed
   # as it's at the end of the regex.
   my $n = () = ($_[0] =~ m/\Q$_[0]\E/g);
   ```

For more detailed information on using regular expressions in Perl, see [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) and [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).